# Regex to return array of URL parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen a number of posts on matching/replacing a path like:

```
/login/:id/:name
```

However, I'm trying to figure out how I can return an array containing only the names of the params; `id`, `name`

I've got the Regex down: `/:[^\s/]+/g, "([\\w-]+)"` just struggling with the match.

Comment: I could split, loop and `substr` to check the patterns, but I'm hoping for something cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop because `match` won't grab capture groups in a global regex, so you'll end up having some extra character you don't need:

```
var url = '/login/:id/:name';

var res = [];
url.replace(/:(\w+)/g, function(_, match) {
  res.push(match);
});

console.log(res); //=> ["id", "name"]
```

You can also use this helper:

```
String.prototype.gmatch = function(regex) {
  var result = [];
  this.replace(regex, function() {
    var matches = [].slice.call(arguments, 1, -2);
    result.push.apply(result, matches);
  });
  return result;
};

var res = url.gmatch(/:(\w+)/g); //=> ["id", "name"]
```

Comment: Seems to work unless there are non-varaible splits, for instance: `/user/:id/login/:name` returns the `id` but the second value is `undefined`